# Installing ElasticSearch and Kibana 6.2 on a Raspberry PI 2

Tags: elasticsearch, raspberry-pi, kibana, elasticsearch-6, kibana-6

For the last week or so, I have been trying to get kibana and elasticsearch to run on my Raspberry PI (because, why not?).

Elsaticsearch setup was not that much of a burden, as the official `.deb` package is compatible, so it was just a matter of tweaking the settings.

The story is a bit different for kibana... I managed to start it locally from the official tarball by removing the provided node binary and linking to the globally available one.  So far, so good. However, I would like to set it up as a service, with the folders in the appropriate location, mimicking an official install.

I am looking for advice on how to achieve that goal. I have two paths in mind:

- creating an `arm` debian package from the kibana source that I could then install using `dpkg`. In such a case, does anyone have knowledge about the kibana build process and where changes would have to be made?
- trying to replicate the `.deb` behaviour manually, by setting up the required bash scripts to copy the files where required, create appropriate users, etc. What would be the points of focus and what should I be careful not to forget?

Comment: How did you manage to run Kibana locally ? Did you install the 64 bit image on Raspberry Pi ?

Comment: I donwloaded the zip file from elastic web site, unzipped, went to bin directory, and deleted the node binary. I then recreated a symlink to my globally installed node.